# pygame - how to display png images in sequence as stored in a list without using classes/objects, Sprite or any other module?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am beginner and I am trying to create a basic space invader game using pygame. In the game, when the bullet collides with the enemy spaceship, there should an explosion effect. I have added all the png images in the correct sequence in a list so when the explosion happens, I want those images to be drawn to create a gif like animation. Its happening but with some flickering. I need help with the explosion function without complicating (for now) using any classes / objects or modules.

```
import pygame

import math

import random

pygame.init()  # initialized pygame

# create the window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# background
bg = pygame.image.load('space_background.jpg')

# title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

# My Space Ship
playerImg = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
playerX = 380
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0

# Enemy Space Ship
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 736)
enemyY = random.randint(10, 100)
enemyX_change = 1
enemyY_change = 40

# player spaceship bullet
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 500
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 1
# ready - when the bullet is not visible on the screen and spaceship can fire it
# fire - when the bullet is fired and still visible on the screen
bullet_state = "ready"
score = 0


# explosion
exImg0 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion00.png').convert()
exImg1 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion01.png').convert()
exImg2 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion02.png').convert()
exImg3 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion03.png').convert()
exImg4 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion04.png').convert()
exImg5 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion05.png').convert()
exImg6 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion06.png').convert()
exImg7 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion07.png').convert()
exImg8 = pygame.image.load('explosions/regularExplosion08.png').convert()

explosionImg = [exImg0, exImg1, exImg2, exImg3, exImg4, exImg5, exImg6, exImg7, exImg8]


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 20, y + 12))


# collision function
def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.hypot(enemyX - bulletX, enemyY - bulletY)
    if distance < 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# explosion function
def explosion(x, y):
    for img in [exImg0, exImg1, exImg2, exImg3, exImg4, exImg5, exImg6, exImg7, exImg8]:
        screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
        screen.blit(img, (x, y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # background image loading
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -1

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    # get the bullet x coordinate of player spaceship
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # player spaceship movement
    playerX += playerX_change

    # stopping the player spaceship at the border
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX > 736:
        playerX = 736

    # bullet movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 500
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    # calling the function to display my spaceship
    player(playerX, playerY)

    # calling the function to display bullet
    # bullet_state(playerX, bulletY)

    # enemy spaceship movement
    enemyX += enemyX_change

    # stopping enemy spaceship at the border
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 0.7
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -0.7
        enemyY += enemyY_change

    # collision
    collision = isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY)
    if collision:
        explosion(enemyX, enemyY)
        bulletY = 500
        bullet_state = "ready"
        score += 1
        print(score)
        enemyX = random.randint(0, 736)
        enemyY = random.randint(10, 100)

    # calling the function to display enemy spaceship
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    # update method to update every action in the screen
    pygame.display.update()
```

[bullet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5swG.png)
[player spaceship image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGVss.png)
[enemy spaceship image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vDbg.png)
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVkoD.jpg)
[explosion pngs](https://kidscancode.org/blog/img/Explosions_kenney.zip)

Comment: Your `explosion()` function blits all of the images to the `screen` surface one after the other  but does not do `pygame.display.update()` or `flip()` between them, which means that only the last image will actually get displayed to the users window when the `update()` gets called later. Pygame does double buffering which means that what you blit to the screen is put on the background copy of the screen and is only displayed to the real display when `update()` or `fill()` causes the background copy to be copied to the display.

Comment: Thanks @GlennMackintosh! Here's what I tried from your comment:

`# explosion function
def explosion(x, y):
    i = 0
    while i < len(explosionImg):
        screen.blit(explosionImg[i], (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        i += 1`

It doesn't seem to be working. Firstly, should I stick with 'for' loop? Also, do need to add a delay in the main game loop (I am not sure how exactly that would be done though)?

Comment: Avoid my last comment. I figured out how to add delay in reading each image from the list. I did 'import time' and used it in my explosion function as:

`def explosion(x, y):
    i = 0
    while i < len(explosionImg):
        screen.blit(explosionImg[i], (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.03)
        i += 1`

The result is exactly how I wanted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was not recommending that you call `update()` in `explsion()`. In fact you should **not**! I was just trying to explain that without `update()` or `flip()` you would not see the intermediate blits.

Comment: What I understood was putting it right at running through each image would keep it on screen for a while. Could you be please more precise with what you proposed? Your version of code would really help. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what made it to work. I did `import time` and updated my explosion function as shown below. It now works exactly how I wanted it to be:

```
def explosion(x, y):
# changed to while loop from for loop
i = 0
    while i < len(explosionImg): # go through the entire length of images from list    
        screen.blit(explosionImg[i], (x, y))
        pygame.display.update() # update display with every image as suggested by Glenn in the comment
        time.sleep(0.03) # delay of 0.03 seconds after displaying an image
        i += 1
```

Side Note - I also scaled each image using `pygame.transform.scale(exImg0, (75, 75))` for better visuals.

Comment: This is not a good solution to your problem. As a general rule you should not call `update()` or `flip()` multiple times in your main game loop, since that will tend to cause flickering effects as a result of not everything else being drawn yet, so you should not call that in `explosion()`. Further you should never call `sleep()` anywhere in your game since it blocks all other things from happening (no bullets or enemies moving elsewhere while this is happening).

Comment: No wonder it isn't the right solution rather a poor workaround which only a novice like me can try out. However, there are tons of other areas where the code can be improved. Like I mentioned in my comment above, can you please provide your version of fix. I am quite sure, that would be a good learning for me. Thanks!